# Does Arcane Abjuration permanently banish creatures below the threshold?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, cleric

Arcana domain Clerics get a Channel Divinity option called **Arcane Abjuration**. Here's the relevant part of the description:

> After you reach 5th level, when a creature fails its saving throw against your Arcane Abjuration feature, the creature is banished for 1 minute (as in the banishment spell, no concentration required) if it isn't on its plane of origin and its challenge rating is at or below a certain threshold, as shown on the Arcane Banishment table.

The spell description for banishment says:

> If the target is native to a different plane of existence than the one you're on, the target is banished with a faint popping noise, returning to its home plane. If the spell ends before 1 minute has passed, the target reappears in the space it left or in the nearest unoccupied space if that space is occupied. Otherwise, the target doesn't return.

It sounds like a creature below the CR threshold for Arcane Banishment is permanently returned to their home plane. However, the phrasing "banished for 1 minute" could be interpreted to say that after one minute they return.

**Are creatures banished by Arcane Abjuration sent back to their home plane permanently, or only for one minute?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## No: Creatures are only banished for the 1 minute duration

From the wording, it appears that the intent of the feature is for the creature to return after one minute, and the phrase "as in the *Banishment* spell" is used to describe what banishment is, as it's not an otherwise defined term within 5e (as opposed to something like "Stunned", which is a defined condition).

Here's the logical flow of the *Banishment* spell:

- If the target is native to the current plane of existence: They return at the end of the spell.
- If the target is native to a different plane of existence:

  - If the spell ends early: They return at the end of the spell.
  - If the spell lasts for the full minute: They are banished permanently.

And here's the logical flow of the Arcane Abjuration feature for comparison:

- If the target is native to a different plane of existence:

  - The target is banished for one minute.

The Arcane Abjuration feature *only* effects creatures that fit the criteria for permanent banishment in the *Banishment* spell, and there's no way to end the effect early (the effect does not require concentration, and is not a spell that can be dispelled), so the only reason to include a duration at all would be to override the permanence clause of the referenced spell.